# Input Field doesn't react in Unity with C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, input-field

I'm not able to get information from my Input Field - I'm even unable to type in a value. [Input- Field - Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XRGmj.jpg)

The code is:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class ButtonPress : MonoBehaviour {

    public InputField GrasInput;
    public Button playbutton;
    int GrasVal=0;

    private void Start()
    {
        Button btn = playbutton.GetComponent<Button>();
        btn.onClick.AddListener(TaskOnClick);
    }

    void TaskOnClick()
    {
        GrasVal++;
        GrasInput.text = GrasVal.ToString();
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong, I wasn't able to find a solution, tried different things to solve problem (not mentioned in the code above, because none of them worked out)? All of the components (GrasInput and playbutton) are connected in the console via the _Manager and this script. (The whole project is uploadet on http://simsoeko.tk/)

Thanks and sorry, I'm just a beginner and really tried to find out why it won't work.

Comment: So, on the button click, you set the inputfields text to the value of GrasVal, which is 0? Does that not happen?

Comment: Yes it does, but I would like to change with an int- input before every button click with my keyboard. Tried different ways, didn't work and no clue why

Comment: Cannot seem reproduce the problem in unity with the given information

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the screenshot provided, your `Text` GameObjects are further down in the hierarchy, also their size seems to "contain" the inputfields, therefor they are blocking the raycasts to your `InputField`s

Either detick `Raycast Target` on your `Text` objects.

Or move the `InputField`s further down in the hierarchy (while remaining children of Canvas)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your scene is missing an EventSystem object. Add it under Hierarchy > create > UI > EventSystem (https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EventSystems.EventSystem.html)

per: https://answers.unity.com/questions/1540770/cant-click-on-input-fields.html